# Leon Mk2 DPF limp mode

Tags: seat-leon, diesel-particulate-filter

im going to try and explain this "adventure" in the clearest way i can.
I have an 07 plate Seat Leon 2.0 diesel FR that has the odd DPF light come up, usually when ive done odd short journeys. Note: my usual journey length is 100+ miles a day. Anyway after a long journey the DPF light goes off fine. However 3 weeks ago the DPF light was on and then the car went into LIMP mode (coil string flashing). 
Took the car to local garage and they did 3 hours of analysis and said the DPF isnt getting the vacuum it requires from the manifold as some of the swirl flaps are loose. After having the car at the garage for 2 weeks, the confirmation that the car couldnt be looked at for another week after and that i need the car for work caused me take the car out of the garage and do the work myself.
Sure enough after taking out the manifold, 4/8 swirl flaps had disintegrated. I replaced the plastic manifold with an aluminium, non-swirl flap version and took the car for a run to try and clear the DPF. Doing north of 70MPH in 5 gear should have given enough for the DPF to clear however LIMP mode again.
The garage did say that they tested the DPF pressure sensor and it was fine and looked at the DPF itself and it was also fine. I need to do an analysis today to see what error codes are coming up but im wondering if anything is coming to front of anyone head while reading this? After analysis my next stops seems to be :

Reset DPF and force regen
DPF sensor replace
Exhaust temperatures sensor replace?

Any input would great!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Any codes? Have you verified the DPF is getting the proper vacuum?

Comment: P2002 which is the standard dpf overflow status code. Haven’t verified the vacuum myself. Any ideas to how I do that?